# How to map a GCP Loadbalancer IP to a custom domain using A Records?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns

I created a Loadbalancer with a network endpoint group to allow Cloud Armor policies to be applied to one of my Cloud Run services. I needed that for whitelisting IPs.

So now I have the IP given by the LoadBalancer I want it to be mapped to a domain I aquired.
The problem is that I have no idea what the A Records for this IP are called or used?

How can I figure this out? I know when using Cloud Run I can choose the Managed Custom Domain section - however this only helps me to map Cloud Run services to domains and not a custom LoadBalancer IP.

Comment: The load balancer has a Front End. Look up the IP address configured for the Front End and use that for the DNS A resource record.

Comment: No more than @JohnHanley: take the IP of the load balancer and add it as a A record in your registrar. Set WWW  in the host part to have an access to the base of your domain name. Set something else is you want subdomains, like <mysub>.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should use the front end IP address of your LB as your A record from your DNS. If you are managing and hosting your DNS records for your domain via GCP, you can refer to [this documentation on how to add a record](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records#add_a_record).

To verify that your A record has been updated, you may use [this tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/). Normally it takes up to 48 to 72 hours [before the changes to propagate](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107?hl=en#:%7E:text=Changes%20with%20your%20domain%20host).